# camel sql insert bean

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, camel-sql

I am trying to insert into sql using a bean in Camel. I must be missing a detail somehow, since the sql is null when reaching the camel sql components inner classes. Should it not be enough to return the map in the insertBean?

My route is defined like this.

```
transform().method(InsertFxBean.class).toF("sql:%s",insertQuery);
```

My insertBean only generates a string, object map and return it.

```
 class InsertBean {

    public Map<String, Object> generateInsert(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

       Map<String, Object> map = exchange.getIn().getBody(Map.class);
       map.put("username", value);
       //add more stuff, using 
       //namedParameters here
       return map;
```

I have followed the [camel apache sql example](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-sql)

I also have tried setting different option parameters on the sql component, like `useMessageBodyForSql`, and batch, with no different outcome.

stackTrace shows sql is emtpy:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question / problem?

Comment: Sorry forgot that part will update question

Comment: Are there additional methods in your InsertBean?

Comment: Hi, no is only one method I can edit question so that it contains that information

Comment: @MRK187 have you defined sequence?

Comment: @BilalShah yes it is,

Comment: Well your SQL is invalid says the Oracle database. Try grabbing the generated SQL and put in a SQL client to see what is the problem.